# Recover files from internal storage in Download Mode

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, data-recovery, lg-g4

I have an unrooted, unencrypted LG G4 that decided to randomly turn off and not boot up again last night. Upon booting into normal mode, the LG logo appears for a long time (longer than usual) and then disappears. If it is plugged in, Windows will detect it as an "Unrecognized USB device".

I can currently boot into Download Mode where it shows a "Firmware Update" screen. LG Bridge seems to recognize the device in Download Mode but I cannot mount it as a drive or anything. I have tried both Windows 10 and Linux.

I installed adb on my computers but upon running `adb devices` it does not seem to detect anything.

Is there a way to recover data from internal storage? I don't care much about the Camera folder or contacts/SMS as those were backed up automatically, but rather the folder I was using to transfer files between PCs.

Comment: Two things to try: boot into [recovery-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) (you've already applied that tag), or try your luck with [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info). In both cases, check whether ADB is able to detect the device.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the same device and I'm in a similar situation. If I try to boot into safe mode or USB-debug mode, the Verizon logo appears and just stays on indefinitely. I *can* boot into download mode, but like you, `adb devices` lists nothing.